# Blank cell and restrict input if other cell is "Nothing". Otherwise have drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

If fx A1 is a drop down list and you choose "Nothing", then B1 should become blank and input should be restricted. If A1 is anything but "Nothing", then B1 should contain a drop down list.

I have tried using data validation, but I don't seem to be able to do it exactly how I want it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I have just tried using data validation: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3843-excel-restrict-value-based-on-another-cell.html

But it just restricts input, it doesn't blank the cells. And I don't know how to  make the drop down list only occur when the other cell is anything but "Nothing".

Comment: You can use visible property .

Answer (score 0):

Type your drop down list values in range and name it, let's say MyList. Then use name manager to create another name, let say RestrictIfNothing. In the RefersTo window type formula:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="Nothing", "", MyList)
```

Remember, address must be with name of sheet. If you want to copy cell with validation, consider removing $$. For clarity, see picture:

[image]

Then set validation on your cell, chose list and =RestrictIfNothing. Names are case sensitive, remember capitalisation.

To clear B1 cell, paste following code to your worksheet (right click on tab and chose 'View Code')

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then Exit Sub
    If UCase(Target) = "NOTHING" Then Target.Offset(, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested this MarcinSzaleniec? When I choose "Nothing" the cell goes blank, but if I choose something else, it says #VALUE!, that is, no drop down list presents itself.

Comment: In my case my list contains 2 values. So I just mark those 2 cells and define their name - Correct?

Comment: just select them and type name in address box in left top corner

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. The list appears when choose something other than "Nothing". But when I choose "Nothing", the latest input in the list is visible, however, the list is no longer active. In other words, it doesn't seem to go blank.
I hope you have an answer. And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might paste the code below into the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have your two dropdowns. It will take the following action.

1. When A1 is set to "Nothing", B1 will be made blank
2. When you select B1 while A1 is "Nothing" the selection will jump to A1

   Option Explicit

   ```
   Const ControlCell As String = "A1"          ' address of dropdown A
   Const TargetCell As String = "B1"           ' address of dropdown B
   Const KeyWord As String = "nothing"
   ```

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       ' 03 Jan 2018

   ```
   With Target
       If .Address = Range(ControlCell).Address Then
           If StrComp(.Value, KeyWord, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               Application.EnableEvents = False
               Range(TargetCell).ClearContents
               Application.EnableEvents = True
           End If
       End If
   End With
   ```

   End Sub

   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       ' 03 Jan 2018

   ```
   With Target
       If .Address = Range(TargetCell).Address Then
           If StrComp(Range(ControlCell).Value, KeyWord, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
               Application.EnableEvents = False
               Range(ControlCell).Select
               Application.EnableEvents = True
           End If
       End If
   End With
   ```

   End Sub

So, in fact, the dropdown in B1 isn't deleted. It is just invisible and inaccessible.